# How to remove Eclipse Mars.1 installed using oomph installer

Tags: 14.04, java, eclipse

I've installed Java-EE Eclipse Mars.1 in Ubuntu 14.04. And now I have problems running different bundles of Eclipse. Besides this installer created a weird shortcut .local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop with parameter Exec:

```
Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest -Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/ -Duser.dir=/home/username/eclipse/jee-mars/eclipse -jar /home/username/eclipse/jee-mars/eclipse//../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher /home/username/eclipse/jee-mars/eclipse/eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.library /home/username/eclipse/jee-mars/eclipse//../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417/eclipse_1612.so -startup /home/username/eclipse/jee-mars/eclipse//../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar --launcher.appendVmargs -exitdata 930019 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -install /home/username/eclipse/jee-mars/eclipse -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest -Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/ -Duser.dir=/home/username/eclipse/jee-mars/eclipse -jar /home/username/eclipse/jee-mars/eclipse//../../../.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
```

The problem is that if I run Eclipse from another bundle it runs under that one shortcut all the time, so I can't understand which bundle is running.

Anyway I want to remove it and install it in a usual way.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse*
```

Doesn't work. It writes *Package 'eclipse' is not installed, so not removed*